# Using Cocoapods in a Workspace with two apps

Tags: xcode, dependencies, cocoapods, podfile

I have two apps (xcode projects) that i want to have in one workspace.  Since Cocoapods usually generates the workspace, i looked to see if it was possible to do this and found some answer.  The recommended Podfile would look like:

```
workspace 'TestWorkspace'

   target 'TestApp1' do
   xcodeproj 'testApp1/testApp1.xcodeproj'
   workspace 'TestWorkspace'
       pod 'AFNetworking'
   end

   workspace 'TestWorkspace'

   target 'TestApp2' do
   xcodeproj 'TestApp2/TestApp2.xcodeproj'
       pod 'MBProgressHUD'
   end
```

(sorry wasn't sure how to have SO format the Ruby code)

So my folder structure looks like a TestWorkspace folder, with the two App projects folders, and the Podfile.  Running `pod install`

> [!] `xcodeproj` was renamed to `project`. Please update your Podfile accordingly.

and..

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `TestApp1` to `../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestApp1/Pods-TestApp1.debug.xcconfig` or include the `../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestApp1/Pods-TestApp1.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`TestApp1/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestApp1/Pods-TestApp1.debug.xcconfig`).

So my question is what changes must be made to wind up with my `TestWorkspace` workspace having three projects: `TestApp1`, `TestApp2`, and `Pods`?

(btw, i changed the true names of my projects/workspaces to pseudo-aliases for the purposes of posting here.  Hopefully, I changed everything faithfully.)

---

**EDIT:** Ok so i fixed the first warning (just a change in podfile syntax from xcodeproj to project).  However, my workspace is definitely not being configured properly.  I don't even see a Pod project after `pod install`ing.

**EDIT2:** OK so i fixed the second warning by setting both project configuration files (debug and release) to "none".  So now I have no errors, but the Pod project is still no where to be found. (Sorry if i'm solving parts of the question but I think its better to add edits than to create a new question).

Answer (score 3):

Use the targets as scopes for the xcproject/workspaces. Update the `podfile` to something like this:

```
workspace 'TestWorkspace'

   target 'TestApp1' do
   xcodeproj 'testApp1/testApp1.xcodeproj'
   workspace 'TestWorkspace'
       pod 'AFNetworking'
   end

   target 'TestApp2' do
   xcodeproj 'TestApp2/TestApp2.xcodeproj'
   workspace 'TestWorkspace'
       pod 'MBProgressHUD'
   end
```

Now run `pod install --verbose`

Comment: so basically "scope" the two target-do's within a workspace?  So I changed my podfile to that.. I'm seeing all good things in the verbose log (not sure if I want to share it -- as it doesn't have redactions) but still no Pod project in "TestWorkspace".  Seems the two projects have been configured seemingly properly as they have Pods groups with non-red xcconfigs.  However the framework group for both has a red `libPods-TestApp*.a`